# Blender layout - Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm currently trying to figure out how someone has laid out their blender; how would I make my geometry nodes look like the picture below(If they're even geometry nodes..)? - I'm new to blender.

[the person](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YW3XxAcLNY8)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOjdS.png)

Comment: Is your question how to display the 3D viewport and the node editor side by side?

Comment: Yes Exactly that! I've been having some trouble figuring out that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not geometry nodes.  You can tell from the upper left corner that he's in the Shader editor in that window.  But if you want Geometry nodes you can modify the standard layout to look like this fairly easily:

- Move the mouse over the border between the 3D viewport and the Outliner until the cursor turns into a two headed arrow.
- Right click and select "Vertical Split"
- A thin line appears.  Move it somewhere in the 3D viewport and left click.

Now you have two windows side by side both with the 3d viewport.  go to the top menu of the one on the right and click the left most icon.  Select "Geometry Node Editor" from the popupu menu:

[image: geometry node editor selected in menu]

You may want to look at the manual's [User Interface Introduction](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/introduction.html) for more details.

Comment: Ah I see now! Thank you it worked. By any chance, do you know how I could get the "principled BDSF" to appear? I can't seem to find it. -- Edit: Grammar

Comment: Principled BDSF is a shader node, not a geometry node.  Switch to _Shader Editor_ if you want that.  (IT's the next entry down in the list)

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much! I've spent the past hour trying to figure out why I couldn't do any of this. Turns out I'm in the wrong area.. Once again, thank you so much for your help :D

Comment: @aserient you're very welcome.  You may want to read the introduction in the manual, or even do the first part of an introductory YouTube tutorial to learn about things like this.

Comment: Will do! Have a good day/night!